# phpmyadmin mysql : SQL query made the whole DB to crash

Tags: mysql

I had two tables, `table_1` has id and ip which belongs to that id. Total of about `11000 IPs`.

## table_1

```
id          ip
1           1.1.1.1
2           2.2.2.2
3           50.50.50.50
................
```

`table_2` has only ip feed in the column `ip_feed` which is of about `1 Million IPs`

## table_2

```
ip_feed #column name 

50.50.50.50
100.100.100.100
45.45.60.98
........
```

when i wrote a join query to check for the matches, The whole database crashed/ cannot be used / late to render.

SQL QUERY USED :

```
select table_1.id,table_2.ip_feed from table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.ip=table_2.ip_feed;
```

Cannot find the root cause, Can some one help me on how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Your names seems wrong.. try this: select table_1.id,table_1.ip,table_2.ip_feed from table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.ip=table_2.ip_feed; .. Other then that, I don't see anything wrong with your query

Comment: Try to index on clumns on which you are performing join.

Comment: in your table_2, use table_1.id how ip_feed.. integer is the best index.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry,It's ip_feed is column name of table_2.

Comment: @Strawberry : Double checked , It's taking enormous time to get the result again and struck. No other activities can be performed.

Comment: What size are the tables?

Comment: @sagi : table_1 size is 1.5 MiB & table_2 size is 34.6 MiB.

Comment: And its not running? did you correct you second table name in the query?

Comment: sagi is right: you are using ip_feed as the table name in the inner join instead of table_2.

Comment: @Strawberry Oops ! sorry ! changed it.

Comment: @sagi changed to table_2. Sorry !

Comment: @Strawberry When checked with query again,No changes, Taking too much time to render. Not sure !

Comment: OK, so provide the EXPLAIN for the query, together with CREATE table statements for all relevant tables. Obviously, edit your question with this information.

Comment: check where you run the query if there is any maximum number of records limit, in standard SQL there is such limit that you need to extend for such query's giant result.

Comment: @Boody : Im running the query from table_1 and that has 11000 datas against table_2 and that has 1 Million IP data.

Comment: @Strawberry Finally worked. It's mystery ! Same query no changes ! couldn't understand ! Thanks all!